# Do weapons collected in the pre game lobby carry over to the match itself?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

Simply put, in many videos I see people in the holding area rushing to pick up the guns in the holding area just to spray the bullets in the face of their friends. However, I was wondering if they keep their guns when they are put on the plane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Kevin mentioned, it is just for the fun of it, and for brand new players it's an area to get a quick chance to play around with the controls, movement and a feel for the weapons.

Although in contradiction to what Kevin said, "Each player starts with the same gear" - there is no gear at all at the start. Every person enters the plane with nothing on them other than the aesthetic clothing they equip (or not equip, yes you can play with just your underwear).

In addition to the comment about dropped gear not coming onto the plane, you can also drop your gear while on the plane, but where it goes I have no idea.

Comment: I would add "although, if you do drop your clothes in the lobby before the game, you don't have them when you get into the plane"

Comment: Everyone *does* start with that holster clothing item which gives a bit of carrying capacity (don't believe they've changed this recently but honestly I haven't checked).

Comment: @Shelby115 You have access to the holster, but you aren't required to wear it and cosmetics don't give you any capacity.

Comment: Whoops, it's not a holster, I meant the Utility belt. Which according to this (like I said, it could be out of date, I haven't checked in game recently) says it gives capacity. https://pubg.gamepedia.com/Utility_Belt

Comment: It's always been weird because it says it does but doesn't seem to. Regardless this question is useless now because there is no more gun spawns in starts. https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/309230/do-clothes-provide-any-bonuses