# Do clothes provide any bonuses?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

Do regular clothing items like shirts or pants provide any bonuses? Other documentation is unclear on this point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The clothing in the game, e.g anything in the right columns of your TAB menu, shirts, coats, masks etc. **all provide no statistical bonuses to your character.**

I thought it was odd that they have a capacity value like other equipment but after some tests of equipping and unequipping various items they have no impact on your capacity total.

The perks of some clothing is that darker or camo items may make it harder for you to be seen out in the field. E.g large dark coats.

Comment: Some friends thought Gaz masks provide defence against unsafe area. Thanks pointing that out

Comment: @Hybris95 There are no "unsafe areas" unless you're referring to the redzones, which those are just bomb drops, and a gas mask isn't saving you from that.

Comment: I meant outside blue circle